# Has Reign Of Kings stopped being supported?

Tags: steam

Around a year or two ago I stumbled across a video of Syndicate playing a game called Reign Of Kings which led me to buy the game. This survival game is the best one I have ever played and I have 300+ hours on it.

The last update was last year I think, are they still supporting this game because I'd love to jump back into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes and no.

The devs basically ran away from RoK and left it in a messy state. The latest patch was actually dropped on October 2nd, but it did more harm than good.

People are complaining about more bugs since that patch hit than ever before. After a little digging, what it looks like is that the majority of the team at Code}{atch left and not much work has been done since.

I haven't played in a bit, but it was like this about a year ago as well. The recent reviews, discussion posts and patch note discussions all say the same.

Comment: That is so disappointing :( ah well, Thanks for the answer tho! Really appreciate it!